# How to find the answer to a riddle that uses a text box for inputting the potential answer and a button for computing the input?

Tags: textbox

I am trying to solve a riddle and I want to find the answer through the inspect element html page the issue is I don't know where to look to find what the button/textbox is calling for to get the correct answer/code.

I tried looking into the HTML line of the text box itself and the button but found nothing on it there was also a lot to look at so I don't know where to look next.